# Gradient on pseudo-elements

Tags: css

How would one style an element with a certain background color and then on both sides pseudo-elements (with a specific width) with the same background colors fading out (gradient from background color alpha 1 to 0)?

I have tried the following (http://plnkr.co/edit/MobgBy5xyJHv7z839jSA?p=preview) but it doesn't work completely:

```
<style>
    .label:after {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(8,170,13,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(8,170,13,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        width: 20px;
        content: ' -- ';
        display: block;
    }

    .label:before {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(8,170,13,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(8,170,13,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        width: 20px;
        content: ' -- ';
        display: block;
    }

    .label {
        background-color: rgba(8,170,13,1);
    }
</style>

<span class="label">test</span>
```

I am not able to get the gradients to be positioned left/right of the base element instead of top/bottom and the gradients only show when there is something defined in the content property (it needs to be empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to position your pseudo elements outside of the span, otherwise they can not be seen properly (because the transparency is masked by the span background)

for this, make them absolutely positioned. (and make the parent position: relative so that it works) and play with the left, top and right properties:

```
.label {
    background-color: rgba(8,170,13,1);
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 15px;
}

.label:before {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(8,170,13,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(8,170,13,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

.label:after {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(8,170,13,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(8,170,13,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    width: 20px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bCbxnD3DmqgqfWz5aV64?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

if you put for example `.label:before { margin-top: -10px; }` you will see that gradients work correctly. **The problem is that there is a green background below them**.
So there are two solutions:

1. Make pseudo-elements gradients from WHITE to green (instead of transparent->green).

```
.label:after {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgb(8,170,13)), color-stop(100%,rgb(255,255,255))); /* change the 0-alpha color to white */
    content: ' ';
    /*float: left;*/ /* you don't need that */
    display: inline-block; /* will move the pseudo-element after the inner text */
}
```

**OR**
2. move pseudo-elements outside the parent element.

```
.label {
    margin: 0 30px; /*make some space for gradients */
}
.label:before, .label:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.label:before {
    left: -30px; /* move the pseudo-element to the left */
}
.label:after {
    right: -30px; /* move the pseudo-element to the right */
}
```